# Best practices using dplyr and timeSeries, ts?

Tags: r, time-series, dplyr

I have 14.5 years of budget data, contract IDs, project types, etc. with which I am trying to build an 18-month, time-series forecast. The data started out as individual payments on contract IDs by (non-continuous) date.  Using Excel, I pivoted into total payments by month; later on I will include total active contracts in a month, composition of contract type, etc. There are a total of 3134 day-rows (out of 5296) on which payments where made - days on which no payments were made are not recorded in this data*.

The features I'm currently using are listed and structured as follows (not all features are below, just trying to get a model piped together using a linear t for now):

```
head(exp)
     Amount Day Month Year t
1  269909.4   5     7 2000 1
2  792078.6   6     7 2000 2
3  140065.5   7     7 2000 3
4  190553.2  11     7 2000 4
5  119208.6  12     7 2000 5
6 1068156.3  16     7 2000 6

> str(exp)
'data.frame':   3134 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Amount: num  269909 792079 140066 190553 119209 ...
 $ Day   : int  5 6 7 11 12 16 17 21 26 28 ...
 $ Month : int  7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ Year  : int  2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 2000 ...
 $ t     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

I'm running into these problems / questions:

1. Dplyr is not at all liking the `ts()` objects I've used in my data.frame, so filtering and sorting by month/contract/contract type isn't working.  What's the best approach here? I'm unsure about the pros/cons of using ts vs. timeSeries, especially as they relate to compatibility with other packages.
2. *Is this easier if I start with vectors of all 5296 days between 7/1/00 and 12/31/14, as well as a `t <- 1:5296` and key these 3134 days of payments to that full list of days?

Comment: I'd recommend using `xts` instead. At least it has elegant conversions from and to data frames, so it is (potentially at least, don't have any empirical evidence) more `dplyr`-friendly.

Comment: @tonytonov Am currently fiddling around with xts - could you put your comment as an answer so that I can check off if this works? In the meantime - what is your opinion about applying the `t <- 1:3134` linear time trend in this case? Is this an invalid use of that technique since the days themselves are at irregular intervals? Or is it sufficient to model a linear trend over this "whole" time horizon - because the lm(), forecast(), etc functions/formulas sort out the spacing differences...?

Comment: Sorry, I might have missed your reply. I don't think this will be a particularly good answer, so I'm fine with it as a comment. You can always answer your own question, by the way. Considering your other questions, I recommend asking them separately, but make sure they are on-topic and reproducible first. Good luck!