# Convert multiple ID's weekly data to time series format

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, smoothing, exponential

Here is the structure of my data

```
structure(list(customer_id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"), state = c("NC", "NC", "NC", 
    "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "NC", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA", "KA"), 
        value = c(20.4, 29, 26, 40, 35, 36, 28, 41, 70, 75, 78, 99, 
        40), Date = structure(c(17784, 17791, 17798, 17805, 17812, 
        17819, 17826, 17833, 17608, 17615, 17622, 17629, 17636), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have so many customers of data from different state with different start and end dates.
I'd like to convert this data to time_series data and perform exponential smoothing using `hw` method.
The code which I have tried to convert to time_series is:

```
temp <- multiple_ts %>%
  group_by(state,customer_id)  %>%
 ts(multiple_ts$value, frequency = 52)
```

I used frequency as 52 because the data is weekly_data,but the code is throwing an error

```
Warning messages:
1: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

my output_data is

```
structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 20.4, 29, 
26, 40, 35, 36, 28, 41, 70, 75, 78, 99, 40, 17784, 17791, 17798, 
17805, 17812, 17819, 17826, 17833, 17608, 17615, 17622, 17629, 
17636), .Dim = c(13L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("customer_id", 
"state", "value", "Date")), .Tsp = c(20.9384615384615, 21.1692307692308, 
52), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

Can someone help me in R.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Those aren't errors, they're warnings. There might be nothing wrong except you have `NA` values.

Comment: I edited the question and posted with output.Can you help me to overcome this problem and get a time_series data and apply exponential smoothing method in R@thelatemail

Comment: Trying to combine `ts` and `dplyr`'s `group_by` doesn't seem to work. You end up with a malformed `matrix`. As per this question, you might be better using the `xts` package's time-series - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28489845/best-practices-using-dplyr-and-timeseries-ts  . Or maybe revert to basic looping - `lapply(split(multiple_ts$value, multiple_ts[c("state","customer_id")], drop=TRUE), ts, frequency=52)`

Comment: I tried the basic looping but I didn't work with larger number of series of data,apart from this also when I tried for exponential_smoothing using `hw` method it showed me as `Error in ets(x, "AAN", alpha = alpha, beta = beta, phi = phi, damped = damped,  : 
  y should be a univariate time series` how can we apply exponential series to multiple time_series of data.Can you help me@thelatemail

Comment: I'm not sure how you ended up with a multiple time series. The code I pasted above `split`s `multiple_ts$value`, which results in the required "*univariate time series*". Did you split the whole `multiple_ts` or `multiple_ts$value`?

Comment: I splited the whole data into time series and applied `hw` method@thelatemail

Comment: Try just on the `value` variable. It seems your `hw` function is expecting a univariate time series.

Comment: I've used this method `double_exp2 <- holt(temp2$NC.A,h = 120)` .The code is executing but how can I apply for the all the time_series data ?